# Can I Update One Cell From Two Other Cell In Same MYSQL Table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to update a single row multiple time. when i update it from one cell it update successfully but when i update it from two cell one of them updated while another want is not.

the MYSQL Table Registration is:

```
CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `Reg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Arrears` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Current_Bill` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Current_Surcharge` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Reg_id`),
  KEY `Reg_id` (`Reg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

when i update `Arrears` from `Current_Bill` and update `Current_Bill` to `0`. it works.
but when i update `Arrears`from `Current_Bill` and update `Current_Bill` to `0` and update `Arrears` from `Current_Surcharge` and `Current_Surcharge` to `0` then `Current_Surcharge` is updating to `Arrears` and `Current_Surcharge` updating to `0` and also `Current_Bill` Updating to `0` but `Arrears` can not be updated from `Current_Bill`

The PHP Code Is:

```
 <?php
    include("Database/connection.php");

    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM registration,billing_month WHERE Bill_id=(SELECT MAX(Bill_id) FROM billing_month)";
    $result = $link->query($sql); 

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $currentsurcharge = $row['Current_Surcharge'];
            $currentbill = $row['Current_Bill'];
            $arrears = $row['Arrears'];

            $updatearrearsfromcurrentbill = $arrears + $currentbill;
            $updatecurrentbilltozero = 0;
            $updatearrearsfromcurrentsurcharge = $arrears + $currentsurcharge;
            $updatecurrentsurchargetozero = 0;

            if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime($duedate)) 
            {
            // thid query is not working while the other 
            // Update Arrears From Current Bill when Bill Is Not Pay On Due Date
             $sql_update5 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Arrears`=             $updatearrearsfromcurrentbill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
            // Update Current Bill To Zero 
            $sql_update6 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatecurrentbilltozero WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
            // Update Arrears From Current Surcharge when Bill is not pay on due date
            $sql_update7 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Arrears`= $updatearrearsfromcurrentsurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
            // Update Current Surcharge to Zero
            $sql_update8 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge` = $updatecurrentsurchargetozero WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

            mysqli_query($link, $sql_update5);
            mysqli_query($link, $sql_update6);
            mysqli_query($link, $sql_update7);
            mysqli_query($link, $sql_update8);
    }

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify additional parameters in the where clauses to achieve what you want because currently they ALL simply user `where Reg_id=$regid` - so in essence you overwrite the `arrears` data with the second query. In both cases you say, in your comments, that the query should update the `arrears` if the bill is not paid by due date - that field can only hold one value.

Effectively, the way it is written currently, your sql is the same as:-

```
$sql_effective="update `registration` set 
    `arrears`='$updatearrearsfromcurrentsurcharge',
    `current_bill`='$updatecurrentbilltozero',
    `current_surcharge`='$updatecurrentsurchargetozero'
    where `reg_id`='$regid';";
```

You need to clarify your logic on what you want to achieve under certain conditions - I'm not clear on what your requirements are.

Based on your further comments, this might suffice. ( Note that there is only 1 update query! ):

```
$sql_update = "update `registration` set 
    `arrears`=".abs( $arrears + $currentbill + $currentsurcharge ).",
    `current_bill`=0,
    `current_surcharge`=0
    where `reg_id`='$regid';";
```

Comment: i have four Field in Table ie
**1. id**
**2. Arrears**
**3. Current_Bill**
**4. Current_Surcharge.**
 
I want to Update `Arrears` From `Current_Bill` And `Current_Surcharge `and Send `0` to `Current_Bill` and `Current_Surcharge`. that's it

Comment: wow it's working @RamRaider .  can you please tell me that why we use `.abs`

Comment: There is no real necessity to use abs - it is simply a mathematical operator - it ensures that the value is always a positive number. You could simply say `arrears=( $arrears + $currentbill + $currentsurcharge )`

Comment: i have'nt permission to give you vote. your answer is appriatiable. thank you again @RamRaider

Comment: @RamRaider Good job on solving this. OP posted this many times; finally, a solution ;-)